# Grails 2.3.5 integration test

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.3.5.

Here is my Integration test located at `test/integration/x.y.z.TestIntegrationSpec.groovy`

```
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec

class TestIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec{
  def "test"(){

  setup: 
    " just a test"
  when:

      1 == 1

  then:

      true
  }
}
```

Results in the following:

```
Fatal error running tests: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
.Tests FAILED 
|

Error |
Error executing script TestApp: java.lang.NullPointerException (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try running the test case with --stacktrace option and see what might be going wrong?

Comment: Error 
|
java.lang.NullPointerException
Error |
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error |
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Error |
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
Error |
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
Error |

Comment: execute like this and add full stactrace to description "test-app integration --stacktrace"

Comment: Run test using `test-app :integration` (Note the colon `:`). If there is still an error, then follow as advised `test-app :integration --stacktrace`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it works with the correct database migration plugin.
In my case runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8" worked
again:-
grails:2.3.7
groovy:2.1.9

Comment: Which "database-migration" plugin was failed?

Comment: I've created the new grails-2.3.5 app with your test code in it. After that I had run `grails test-app` and all works perfectly. By default Grails 2.3.5 has "database-migration:1.3.8". So, the problem not in the "database-migration".